# Are certain logP values eluted when 100% methanol is used as the solvent in a C18 column?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I have used a C18 sep-pak to concentrate metabolites in a chemically complex solution. The column was first washed with pure water, 75% methanol:water mix, and finally the compounds eluted with 100% methanol.

What I am wondering is what chemical properties that I can infer from this information? I know I would have washed the very polar compounds away, and in pure methanol, I would expect compounds of a semi-polar nature to be eluted. Can I assume that these compounds would have a specific LogP range? I cannot find an answer online anywhere, so I guess the answer must be no, and if so, why not?

There is one (or more) compound of a biologically active nature in this complex mix. I am wondering if I can use the elution conditions to understand some of the chemical properties of the compounds eluted. Further, I did FT-ICR-MS on this mix, and I would like to look at a list of compound hits from the mass spec databases and understand how feasible a particular hit is based on its polarity.

Answer (score 1):

HPLC is often used to determine lipophilicity in industry, as the original methods to determine logP by partitioning between octanol and water was not particularly amenable to high-throughput assay.

Lipophilicity values measured by HPLC are often reported as cLogP / cLogD (where c is relating to the fact that the value has been determined by some form of chromatography).

Experimentally, a C18 column is used with an acetonitrile/water solvent system, buffered appropriately. Unlike with the octanol/water procedure, different companies run these HPLC assays differently, and as such they aren't as comparable (i.e. if you ran 20 compounds through a GSK assay, and the same 20 compounds through a Pfizer assay, the precise values for cLogD obtained in each case would vary, even if the general trend remained the same).

In terms of *you* doing this yourself, you'd first need to find a training set of compounds with known and reliable values. If you know paracetamol comes of at x mins and has a  literature logP of y, and ibuprofen comes off at z mins and has a literature logP of w, you can interpolate. When you then run an unknown sample, its retention time using your method can be used to predict the cLogP/D (keep in mind that you'd need a far greater training set than 2 compounds).

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. So because I am just using the disposable C18 sep pak, and not HPLC, it sounds like I am out of luck when it comes  to drawing conclusions regarding the nature of the molecules that were eluted.

Comment: Oh sorry. I never even made the connection that C18 might be anything other than a HPLC column!  But yes, you'd be unwise to draw too many conclusions from that.